# "Unknown Provider" error when using Angular ui-router when using service in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use a Service (rates service) in my Controller (rates controller) and get an "Error: Unknown Provider". Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Cheers!

**rates.contoller.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('print.module').controller('ratesCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', '$rootScope', 'ratesService', function ($http, $scope, $rootScope, ratesService) {
    ratesService.getRatesDataService();
}]
)})();
```

**rates.service.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('print.module').service('ratesService', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    vm = this;

    function getRatesDataService() {
        console.log("test");
        return this.$http.get("api/Rates/GetRates");
    }

    //}
}]
)
})();
```

**print.module.js**

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var module = angular.module('print.module', [
    'ui.router',
]);
module.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/print');
    $stateProvider
        .state('print', {
            url: '/print',
            templateUrl: "Public/scripts/sharedViews/printNavbar.html"

        })
        .state('print.rates', {
            url: "/rates",
            controller: 'ratesCtrl',
            templateUrl: "Public/scripts/rates/rates.view.html",
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })

   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

}());
```

**view (scripts tags only for reference)**

```
<body ng-app="print.module">
<div ui-view></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>            
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/public/scripts/print.module.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/public/scripts/books/books.controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/public/scripts/terms/terms.controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/public/scripts/rates/rates.service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/public/scripts/rates/rates.controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/public/scripts/services/modals.service.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `$scope` inside Service

Comment: I took it out, but unfortunately the issue remains.

Comment: I believe it's some kind of very basic question, but there is no more specific answer, because I even don't know what the name of Provider is not found. You can see this information in console right the next after the error message.